# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` that adopts `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are implemented.

There are outlets for dataSource & delegate in storyboard. Single selection is chosen for TableView. Show selection on touch is checked.

I run project on the simulator, touch table cell, got `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` call, but  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` are never called.

What did I forgot? What can affect TableView in this way?

P.S. I know, there is a plenty of questions like this, but I've spent a few hours googling and reading stackoverflow and still didn't solve my problem.

TestViewController.h:

`@interface TestViewController : ViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

`@end`

TestViewController.m:

```
@interface TestViewController ()
@property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected");
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"highlighted");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FilterCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"some text";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: don't you think it would be helpful to add your code? or do you expect us to have mind reader capabilities?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I'll add it, but there is nothing special. I've even changed my class to a simple one just for testing

Comment: @Serhii Yakovenko, it's ViewController inherited from STableViewController (for "load more" implementation). Bad name, I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it. Problem was in a library that project uses.

My ViewController was inherited from a library's ViewController implementation and it was catching all the gestures.

Comment: Please explain further to help others and then select this is the answer.

Comment: This got me everytime,
Check your gesture recognizer, if you add gesture recognizer to table view,  the didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not running.

Comment: This got me more than once too @EdwardAnthony. I managed to solve it by not cancelling touches in view.

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[tapRec setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`

Comment: Forest, you're a Goddamn genius!

Answer (score 14):

Hard to say without seeing code, but try this:

1) The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is from `UITableViewDelegate`, **NOT dataSource**, do you have it connected?!

2) Check the signature of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` carefully. Copy paste it from some trusted source. Maybe some mistype there.

3) Be sure that outlets are connected properly. Stop it somewhere with a debugger, say `viewDidLoad` and print dataSource & delegate (`po self.tableView.dataSource` debugger command), make sure they point to the correct object.

4) Does the row get selected visually? Maybe you have `cell.userInteractionEnabled` set to NO in code or storyboard?

5) Table view has a selection property in storyboard: (Is it ok?)
[image]

**6) Maybe you have table in editing mode? Log it from debug to see.**

7) Does the row get's selected from point of view of `indexPathsForSelectedRows` method? What if you override and log calls to cell's `selected` accessor?

Comment: 1) Yes, both are connected (delegate & dataSource). didHighlightRowAtIndexPath is called. 2) copied from ios docs (just in case). 3) logged both connections, they're ok

Comment: I see visual effects and logs of cell highlight; cell's userInteractionEnabled is checked and I don't change it in code; single selection for tableview is set.

Comment: 6) in didHighlight tableView.editing is NO; and even changing to 'single selection in editing mode' didn't help. 7) I'm checking it also in didHighlight and it's always null

Comment: wow, I've got a selected cell by long tap on it (really long and really unnatural) and now I can't select any other cell. Also I've notices that changing cell's selection style to blue (from gray) in storyboard or code doesn't really change it.

Comment: the problem was in a library used there, but still many thanks for your help!

Comment: "1) The didSelectRowAtIndexPath is from UITableViewDelegate, NOT dataSource, do you have it connected?!" Yup, that did it!