# TableViewController Detect Row Tap with Static Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm using a TableViewController that has a table with 2 sections of static cells. This is embedded in a view controller. I cannot get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to run when I tap the cells. I've already check all of the usual suspects from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255927/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called) question as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952688/didselectrowatindexpath-not-being-called?noredirect=1&lq=1) one. When I try with a table view inside a viewcontroller with a dynamic table, I am able to get it to work just fine. Is there an issue with using a TableViewController with static cells that would not allow for using didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Here is what I have in the custom class for the TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class OptionTableViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet var optionsTable: UITableView!


let numberOfRows = [7,2]

let cellIdentifier = "OptionCells"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.optionsTable.delegate = self
    self.optionsTable.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    var rows = 0

    if(section < numberOfRows.count){
        rows = numberOfRows[section]
    }

    return rows

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

}
}
```

**Update:**
I tried replacing the tableviewcontroller and the viewcontroller it was embedded in but I am still not able to get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to run.

**Update 2:**
Does anyone know if this is possible in Swift 3? I found a working example using Swift 2.2 with a tableviewcontroller and static cells [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2). Maybe there is a bug doing this with Swift 3?

Comment: There are some useful things to try here that you may find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20020180/1655378

Comment: Thanks but I had actually already tried those suggestions as well.

Comment: How do you embed the TVC in the view controller?

Comment: @pbasdf Using an embed segue from a container view inside the view controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, so it turns out that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is no longer correct in Swift 3. The correct usage is now didSelectRowAt. I didn't see this mentioned anywhere except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701290/xcode-8-swift-3-didselectrowat-vs-didselectrowatindexpath) question which I stumbled upon.

**This:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

**Not This**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have the wrong table view hooked up. Normally, a UITableViewController has it's tableView in the view property and you don't need to set up the data source and delegate programatically.

Comment: I double check and even "re-hooked" it up. I figured that I didn't need the data source and delegate but put them in anyway when I couldn't get it to work.